# DetectSpikeBySsa get model parameters and retrain it (ML.NET v1.2.0)

Tags: c#, .net, ml.net

I'm working on a TimeSeries model, and need to analyze the anomalies of the data collection. To do that, I'm using **DetectSpikeBySsa**. But the thing is, what I need now it is to retrain the model for the future data.

I've already search for documentation, and I only got about other types of model, like LinearRegression.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/how-to-guides/train-machine-learning-model-ml-net

```
// Pipeline that I used
var pipeline = context.Transforms.DetectSpikeBySsa(
                            outputColumnName: nameof(DataPredicted.Prediction),
                            inputColumnName: nameof(DataPoints.value),
                            confidence: 99,
                            pvalueHistoryLength: data.Count() / numberOfDays,
                            trainingWindowSize: data.Count(),
                            seasonalityWindowSize: data.Count() / numberOfDays);
// Train and Save the model locally
ITransformer trainedModel = pipeline.Fit(dataComplete);
context.Model.Save(trainedModel, dataComplete.Schema, file);


// Loading the trained model in other instance
ITransformer trainedModel = context.Model.Load(file, out var modelInputSquema);

// After this I would like to retrain the model and analyze the differences between before and after.
```

The trained model is working well with the old data, but of course we need to retrain the model using the new data.

So, the questions are:

1. How to get the **parameters** of the trained model (DetectSpikeBySsa)?
2. How to **retrain** the model and compare the old one?

Thanks a lot! Any information will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently one cannot re-train this model. According to docs.microsoft the following algorithms can be retrained.

[Re-Train a Model in ML.Net](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/how-to-guides/retrain-model-ml-net)

- AveragedPerceptronTrainer
- FieldAwareFactorizationMachineTrainer
- LbfgsLogisticRegressionBinaryTrainer
- LbfgsMaximumEntropyMulticlassTrainer
- LbfgsPoissonRegressionTrainer
- LinearSvmTrainer
- OnlineGradientDescentTrainer
- SgdCalibratedTrainer
- SgdNonCalibratedTrainer
- SymbolicSgdLogisticRegressionBinaryTrainer

It may be possible to add to your data and train a new model and save it with a different name. You could then evaluate both models and take the one with the better score. You may also want to try a different algorithm if the model perform poorly or alter the features of you model.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @brandon. I will try your idea, "train a new model and evaluate the models", it seems the best solution for now.